# Building a defaultdict whose values are defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there any particular reason that my application says the argument must be callable or none type? I'm pretty sure this is how you'd instantiate a defaultdict with a defaultdict as its values.

```
dict = defaultdict(defaultdict(set))
```

Answer (score 4):

The argument provided to the `defaultdict` constructor must be a zero-argument callable (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)), so `defaultdict(defaultdict)` does work, but `defaultdict(defaultdict(set))` does not. You can 'cheat' a little though:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
```

That way you provide a zero-argument callable in the form of the `lambda` function which in turn, when called, returns the appropriate default value you want.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. If I've got this right, default(set) returns an object, as said above, instead of a type; therefore, the instantiation of the outer defaultdict throws an error because it receives an object instead. Can't I do this, technically then:

defaultdict(type(defaultdict(set))

Comment: Never mind; this creates problems as well because it doesn't instantiate the inner dictionary instead, rather just giving a type.

Comment: That 's a clever idea, but I don't think it works. `type(defaultdict(set))` is `defaultdict` where the default callable is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a function for `defaultdict` constructor but `defauldict(set)` is `defaultdict` object instead. If you want to build a `defaultdict` whose values are `defaultdicts` you can use lambdas:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = lambda: defaultdict(dd)
x = dd()
x['foo']['bar']['foobar'] = 1
```